# How do I use the sed command to remove all but the first three characters in a line?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

How do I use the sed command to remove all but the first three characters in a line?  For example, the line as follows:

**Wednesday**

Should become

**Wed**

```
sed -i -e 's/Ive tried everything, but the right thing//g' $HOME/filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GNU sed** has a special flag for this purpose:

```
sed -e 's/.//4g'
```

The `4` here instructs `sed` to start from the fourth occurence of the pattern to substitute.

Comment: @XXX You're welcome. Note that if this is the sole operation, `sed` is a tad overkill and `cut -c 1-3` or `grep -o ^...` would be more suitable (and POSIX-friendly). But you would probably miss the `--in-place` option.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
sed -re 's/^(...).*$/\1/'
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line;
- `(...)` matches three characters and puts them in group #1;
- `.*$` matches everything till the end of the line;
- `\1` is the content of group #1.

The `-r` / `--regexp-extended` option is required to use groups.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer/example worked great when I tested it.  I'm going with  *sed -e 's/.//4g'*  just because it is shorter.